# Overiding functions defined in an external script

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write some userscripts in JavaScript to be used with browser extensions.

In a website, I tried overriding a function defined in an external javascript, with Object.defineProperty. but it seems that this breaks the external script, because other codes in the external scripts (that are essential to the original website) seems to be not executing as well.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- injected script, injected via Userscript -->
    <script> 
      Object.defineProperty(window, 'originalFunction', { get: function() { return overridingFunction; } });
    </script>
    <!-- injection end -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="/external-javascript.js">
    <script> originalFunction(); </script>
    <script> anotherEssentialFunction(); </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and `http://domain/external-javascript.js` looks like this"

```
...
function originalFunction() {
  some codes here;
}
...
function anotherEssentialFunction() {
  ....
}
```

and this was preventing anotherEssentialFunction from running. In the console, I see `TypeError: can't redefine non-configurable property originalFunction` and `ReferenceError: anotherEssentialFunction is not defined`
Is this expected in this situation, or there should be other problem causing it that is not described here? How can I safely override original function without causing such an error?

Answer (score 1):

`Object.defineProperty` takes the *name* of a function as a parameter, so you'd have to do this instead:

```
Object.defineProperty(window, 'originalFunction', { 
  get: function() { 
    return overridingFunction; 
  } 
});
```

Or if that's all the getter does, simply:

```
window.originalFunction = overridingFunction;
```

But if the other functions need to call the original function, you can't really override it without breaking the functions that rely on its behavior. If you're just trying to execute custom code *in addition to* the original code, you can do this:

```
var origFn = window.originalFunction;
window.originalFunction = function () {
  customFunction();
  origFn.apply(this, [].slice.call(arguments));
};
```

**Update**:

Based on your comment, it sounds like you're wanting to not only override the original function but also prevent the external script from redefining that function. You can maybe add a no-op setter to avoid the external script from getting an error when trying to define it:

```
Object.defineProperty(window, 'originalFunction', { 
  get: function() { 
    return overridingFunction; 
  },
  set: function(ignored) { } 
});
```

Comment: (I forgot to include quotation marks, edited, thank you for pointing out though) It seems that if I use `window.originalFunction = overridingFunction`, original function gets redefined by the external script, and this was the reason for me to try using getters. In my situation, the original function is actually called several times in other scripts in the external script, but I thought they should work with the new overriding function, or maybe this is not true and is the cause of the problem.. I will try your last suggestion. Thank you!

Comment: I've tried the way you told in updated answer, and this does removes a console error `TypeError: can't redefine non-configurable property originalFunction`. However, `anotherEssentialFunction` isn't defined still and I would like to know how to fix.